# Finding a function with given property.

Tags: functions

Let $ f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) $ for all real numbers $x,y$ and $ f(x) = 1 + xg(x)$ where $ \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 1$ Then the function $f(x)$ is

$a)$ $e^{x}$

$b)$ $2^{x}$

$c)$ A non constant polynomial

$d)$ equal to $1$ for all real $x$

Since $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ this must be a power function.

But I'm confused between $a$ and $b$.

How to proceed $?$

Answer (score 3):

**a)** Is the right solution :
$$e^x=1+x+x\varepsilon (x)$$ where $\varepsilon (x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$. Set $g(x)=1+\varepsilon (x)$ and you'll have your result.

**b)** Fails because if such a $g$ exist, then the derivate of $x\mapsto 2^x$ at $0$ would be 1 which is obvioulsy false.

**c)** and **d)** are obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is clearly option $a)$, that is $e^x$. This is because, the condition $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)\to1\implies \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}=1$, which is only true for $f(x)=e^x$ and false for $2^x$. Regarding option $c)$ , your reasoning using functional equations is right. As regards option $d)$, the condition that $f(x)=1+xg(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=1$ is not satisfied.

Comment: @projectilemotion thanks! edited the post.